# Examples of self-dual categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, duality-theorems, monoidal-categories

Call a category $C$ *self-dual* if there exists an equivalence of categories $F: C \rightarrow C^{op}$. I am looking for examples of self-dual categories. Rigid monoidal categories and more generally star-autonomous categories are self-dual essentially by definition. What are other classes of examples? Are there self-dual categories that do not admit a star-autonomous monoidal structure?

Comment: How about any poset that is isomorphic to its opposite?

Comment: Or any group viewed as a category with one object? (The equivalence is the isomorphism $G\cong G^{\mathrm{op}}$, $g\mapsto g^{-1}$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The category $\text{Mod}_f(\mathbb{H})$ of finite rank modules over the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ is an example that doesn't admit any closed monoidal structure; the self-duality is given by taking the $\mathbb{H}$-linear dual, which is canonically an $\mathbb{H}^{op}$-module, then applying the isomorphism $\mathbb{H} \cong \mathbb{H}^{op}$ given by quaternionic conjugate to get an $\mathbb{H}$-module structure.

This category admits no closed monoidal structure because no nonzero object has a commutative monoid of endomorphisms and hence no nonzero object could be the monoidal identity (by the Eckmann-Hilton argument). And if the zero object is the monoidal identity in a *closed* monoidal category then every hom space is zero.