# Why is $\mathcal{C}$ equivalent to $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ when $\mathcal{C}$ is a compact category?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monoidal-categories, equivalence-of-categories

I came across the statement that a compact closed category $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to its dual category $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ (see e.g. [this StackExchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4466797/examples-of-self-dual-categories)).

This fact seems to be regarded as obvious as it would follow basically from the definition of a compact category.

The definitions I'm working with are the following:

> [Definition 1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact%20closed%20category): A compact closed category, or simply a compact category, is a symmetric monoidal category in which every object is dualizable (i.e. it has left and right duals).

> [Definition 2.1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object): A *right duality* between objects $A, A^* \in (\mathcal{C}, \otimes, I)$ consists of a morphism $\varepsilon_A : A^* \otimes A \to I$ called the *counit* and a morphism $\eta_A : I \to A \oplus A^*$ called the *unit*, such that the following two diagrams commute:
>
> $$
>     \array{
>        A^\ast \otimes (A \otimes A^\ast)
>          &\overset{\text{id}_{A^\ast} \otimes \eta_A}{\longleftarrow}&
>        A^\ast \otimes 1
>        \\
>        {}^{{\alpha^{-1}_{A^\ast,A, A^\ast}}}_{{\simeq}}\downarrow
>        &&
>        \downarrow^{{\lambda^{-1}_{A^\ast} \circ \rho_{A^\ast}}}_{{\simeq}}
>        \\
>        (A^\ast \otimes A) \otimes A^\ast
>          &\underset{\varepsilon_A \otimes \text{id}_{A^\ast}}{\longrightarrow}&
>        1 \otimes A^\ast
>     }
>   $$
> $$
>     \array{
>        (A \otimes A^\ast)  \otimes A
>          &\overset{\eta_A \otimes \text{id}_A}{\longleftarrow}&
>        1 \otimes A
>        \\
>        {}^{{\alpha_{A,A^\ast, A}}}_{{\simeq}}\downarrow
>        &&
>        \downarrow^{{\rho_A^{-1}\circ \lambda_A}}_{{\simeq}}
>        \\
>        A \otimes (A^\ast \otimes A)
>          &\underset{\text{id}_A \otimes \varepsilon_A}{\longrightarrow}&
>        A \otimes 1
>     }
>   $$
> where $\lambda$ and $\rho$ are the left and right unitor of the monoidal category.
>
> *Left duality* is defined similarly.

> [Definition 2.1'](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence+of+categories): An *equivalence* between two categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ is an equivalence in the 2-category Cat of all categories, hence a pair of inverse functors, hence it is
>
> 1. a pair of functors
>
> $$
>      \mathcal{C} \xrightarrow{F} \mathcal{D} \xrightarrow{G} \mathcal{C},
>    $$
>
> 2. natural isomorphisms
>
> $$
>      F \circ G \cong \text{Id}_{\mathcal{D}}
>    $$
>
> and
>
> $$
>      G \circ F \cong \text{Id}_{\mathcal{C}}
>      \,.
>    $$
>
> This is called an *adjoint equivalence* if the natural isomorphisms
> above satisfy the triangle identities, thus exhibiting $F$ and $G$ as
> a pair of adjoint functors.
>
> Two categories are called *equivalent* if there exists an equivalence
> between them.

I guess that one can somehow construct an adjoint equivalence between $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$, where the components of the unit and counit of the adjunction are given by the $\eta_A$ and $\varepsilon_A$ of the duality.
I cannot figure out how this would work in detail though and I have the suspicion that I am overcomplicating this probably trivial problem.

Can someone please help me understand why $\mathcal{C}$ would *obviously* be equivalent to $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a compact closed category, we have for any object $A$ adjunctions $-\otimes A\dashv -\otimes A^* \dashv -\otimes A$ (see Propositions 2.14 and 2.15 on [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object#relation_to_adjunctable_tensor_products)). Therefore, for any $A,B\in\mathcal{C}$, we have $\mathcal{C}(A,B)\cong \mathcal{C}(A\otimes B^*,I)\cong\mathcal{C}(B^*\otimes A,I)\cong\mathcal{C}(B^*,A^*)$, where $I$ is the monoidal unit. This isomorphism is natural in $A$ and $B$. Let $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ be given by $FA=A^*$ and declare $F$ to act on morphisms according to the isomorphism $\mathcal{C}(A,B)\cong\mathcal{C}(B^*,A^*)$. Using naturality of this isomorphism, one may check that $F$ is indeed a functor, i.e. respects composition and identities. Now, $F$ is essentially surjective because $F(A^{*})=A^{**}\cong A$, and is fully faithful by construction. Therefore, $F$ is an equivalence $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$.

Comment: Ahh! Perfect. That answers my question. Thank you so much :)